# $\frac{f(x)}{x}>c$ for strictly increasing function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

A complete description of the question is like this:

> $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Also $f$ is strictly increasing. Given that $f(0) \geq 0$, is there a $c>0$ satisfying $\frac{f(x)}{x}>c$ for all $0<x \leq 1$?

I think the answer is yes intuitively from sketching a graph. But it seems hard to connect the given conditions to the conclusion in a proof (especially how to make use of the condition $f'$ is continuous).

Comment: If $f(x)=x^3$ there is no such $c$.

Comment: Note that if there is a limit as x tends to zero of zero, what could this imply about $\frac{f(x)}{x}$? If that also tends to zero then there isn't going to be such a constant now is there?

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is
$$
x \mapsto f(x):=\arctan x, \qquad f'(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}>0,
$$ we have, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\arctan x}x \to 0
$$ and there is no such $c>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This totally makes sense for the case $x>0$. I edited the question and what I actually meant is for x in a certain interval, say $0<x\leq 1$. Do you have any idea about that?